# How to get the ids of a table according to the value of a reference field that does not exist in another table?

Tags: mysql

Having tables A and B with the following fields

```
A
-----
id
bID

B
-----
id
```

How can I get all the ids of table A where value of field bID does not exist in table B field id?

In this way having the following data

```
A
-----
id   bID
1    1
2    2
3    3

B
-----
id
1
2
4
5
```

The expected result is id 3 of table A

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use exists logic here:

```sql
SELECT id
FROM A a
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM B b WHERE b.id = a.bID);
```

Answer (score 2):

Here it is :

```
SELECT id FROM A WHERE bid NOT IN (SELECT id FROM B)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `inner join`

```
select * from A left join B on b.id = a.bID where b.id is null
```